# java : How to get Internal details inside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public void two(final BeanForm[] captureddata)
{
  for (BeanForm form : captureddata) 
  {
    if (form.getCyclicType() != null) 
    {
      logger.info("The Cyclic Type is"+ form.getCyclicType().value());
    }

    if (form.getTicketType() != null) 
    {
      logger.info("The Ticket Type is"+ form.getTicketType().value());
    }
  }
}
```

The above code works fine, but the output what I can see in the log file is  (In case the length of the BeanForm is 2 )

```
11/Nov/2011 20:15:51   - The Cyclic Type is  DTI
11/Nov/2011 20:15:51   - The Ticket Type is MMTS
11/Nov/2011 20:15:51   - The Cyclic Type is DTI
11/Nov/2011 20:15:51   - The Ticket Type is MMTS
```

I just wanted to know whether it is possible to  get the  array details also, like to which array this data belongs to 
For example

```
The array[1]  Cyclic Type is  DTI 
The array[2]  Cyclic Type is  SAG
```

Comment: You'd have to change your loop to use an index.By the way; array indices start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an external count:

```
public void two(final BeanForm[] captureddata)
{
  int count = 0;

  for (BeanForm form : captureddata) 
  {
    if (form.getCyclicType() != null) 
    {
      logger.info(count + " The Cyclic Type is"+ form.getCyclicType().value());
    }

    if (form.getTicketType() != null) 
    {
      logger.info(count + " The Ticket Type is"+ form.getTicketType().value());
    }

    count++;
  }
}
```

or as a normal for loop

```
public void two(final BeanForm[] captureddata)
{
  for (int i=0; i<captureddata.length; i++)
  {
    BeanForm form = capturedata[i];

    if (form.getCyclicType() != null) 
    {
      logger.info(i+ " The Cyclic Type is"+ form.getCyclicType().value());
    }

    if (form.getTicketType() != null) 
    {
      logger.info(i+ " The Ticket Type is"+ form.getTicketType().value());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the *index* into the loop - no. You'd need to do that explicitly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < capturedData.length; i++)
{
    BeanForm form = capturedData[i];
    // Now you have both form and i.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to maintain a counter in the for-loop and you can use the counter along with the array[], something like:

```
int i=0;
for-each loop
{
    //print array[i]
    //increment i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void two(final BeanForm[] captureddata)
{
    for (i = 0; i < captureddata.length(); i++) {
        BeanForm form = captureddata[i]
        if (form.getCyclicType() != null) 
        {
            logger.info("The array["+i+"] Cyclic Type is"+ form.getCyclicType().value());
        }

        if (form.getTicketType() != null) 
        {
            logger.info("The array["+i+"] Ticket Type is"+ form.getTicketType().value());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with Matthew's solution
, simply use another counting number and make an increment at the end of the loop.

however, in the log file, do mind whether you wish to start with the "array[0]" or "array[1]"

Comment: Thanks a lot , you people were always helpful as usual . this stackoverflow site  has been  heaven for developers .